monotone convergence of conditional expectation
Let

$(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
$\mathcal F$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ with $\mathcal
   F\subseteq\mathcal A$
$X_n,X$ be non-negative random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$

The monotone convergence theorem for the conditional expectation states, that if $X_n\uparrow X$ almost surely, then $$\lim_n E\left[X_n\mid\mathcal F\right]=E\left[X\mid\mathcal F\right]\;.$$
I really do not understand what the theorem tries to say, since $E\left[X_n\mid\mathcal F\right]$ is increasing only a.s.. $\lim_n E\left[X_n\mid\mathcal F\right]$ may not exist, let alone be a version of a $E\left[X\mid\mathcal F\right]$.
So what is the meaning of $\lim_n E\left[X_n\mid\mathcal F\right]$ here?

$\lim_n E\left[X_n\mid\mathcal F\right]=E\left[X\mid\mathcal F\right];$ almost surely.

My problem is $\lim_n E\left[X_n\mid\mathcal F\right]$  does not make sense, since limit may not exist.

Countable union of null sets is a null set, so everyhting is well defined outside one null set.

Could you please be clearer? Suppose $\lim_n E\left[X_n\mid\mathcal F\right] 1_{A}$ exists, where $A$ is the intersection of ${ X_n \leq X_{n+1}}$.  Then what is the relation between $\lim_n E\left[X_n\mid\mathcal F\right]$ and $\lim_n E\left[X_n\mid\mathcal F\right] 1_{A}$ ?

If you want, you can write the conclusion of the theorem as follows. Suppose that for each $n$, $Z_n$ is a version of $E[X_n|\mathcal{F}]$. Then: (a) With probability $1$, the sequence $Z_n$ converges to a limit; (b) Suppose $Z$ is any random variable which agrees with this limit on a set of probability $1$ (if you like, you can write this as $Z=\liminf_n Z_n$ with probability $1$). Then $Z$ is a version of $E[X|\mathcal{F}]$.
